# How to get list users who likes my page posts with Graph API?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been stuck trying to get list users (user_id, username) who like my own page posts, but didn't work. seems like I need more permissions or these users have to authenticate my Facebook App?
Thank you for your kindly help,
[image]

Comment: Why do you need who liked you page?

Comment: It's for Reward. We post some contents on our Page and get list of users who like these posts will get rewards. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You are not allowed to reward people for linking your page

Comment: @WizKid yes, but what about liking a post on a page? not sure if that is not allowed to reward as well...either way, i believe it is a privacy issue - in general, you cannot access any data of users who did not authorize your app.

Comment: oh yes sure, they have to authorize my Facebook App first. but what kind of permissions should I submit? you have any idea?